# How to remove Border from mx:DateField?

Tags: apache-flex, coding-style, border, skinning, datefield

according the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html) borderThickness is an applicable style, but when I try to set it to anything (would prefer '0') it says "The style 'borderThickness' is excluded by type 'mx.controls.DateField'."

I could style the background color to be the same as the background, but I have an image behind so this will not work.

There must be some way to remove this border!?

Comment: What Border do you want to remove?  A DateField is made up of multiple parts; an image, a TextInput, and the Calendar pop up.  You should be able to change the borderThickness style using ActionScript w/o compiler errors, however if the style is excluded that will most likely have no effect.

Comment: on the TextInput.. it seems strange that it's excluded since it mentions the property in the support docs.. but I got it sorted using Kevin's method below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a protected property in the DateField named textInput.  You can override the DateField class and set style 'borderStyle' of the textInput, which is of type TextInput, to 'none'.  Example:
.

```
public class ExtendedDateField extends DateField {

override protected function createChildren():void{
    super();
    textInput.setStyle('borderStyle','none');
}

}
```

Comment: that looks promising! textInput seems to be null on load though :/  the textInput isn't added until the createChildren function on the ComboBase, i try `override protected function createChildren` in my custom component and it says 'the protected attribute can only be used on class property definitions.. odd since  it's used the way i'm trying to use it in DateField....

Comment: ah i just had the curlies in the wrong place.. works now!  just have to put that style code in the createChildren function

Comment: Roger that, I'll update my answer in case anyone else views it.